# Counting And Summing Disk IOs in Windows

Tags: windows, performance, hard-drive, iostat

Among other (see a [post of mine](http://dr.th.schank.ch/blog/post/3aph)) I am trying to **count and add the number of bytes read/written to a disk**
during a minute/hour/day/... on windows. According to the *Physical Disk Object*
documentation from microsoft (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776376(WS.10).aspx)
there is **Avg. Disk Bytes/Read** and **Disk Reads/sec** which by 
my understanding should multiply to the read bytes per second (on average). 
However, what I get is identical to **Disk Bytes/sec** which is explained by

> Shows the rate, in incidents per
>   second, at which bytes were
>   transferred to or from the disk during
>   write or read operations.

The crux is **during ... operations** which means actually the throughput as 
I understand it, and not the average.

In some other post (Tracking number of IOs to disk on Windows)
 the **transfers/sec** are mentioned, but as I understand it,
this is not correct either?

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to measure what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking at the performance counters that are already being "cooked" and formatted for your viewing pleasure.  Have a look at the RAW counters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394308%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

You could look at *DiskReadBytesPerSec* and *DiskReadsPerSec* and their write counterparts.  You basically sample that twice, and then count the number of micro? seconds between, or do whatever kind of formula you like.  MS provides "cooking" formula's for their counters, so you might want to look into that too.  But if you just want RAW bytes, you should be able to get it there.